# ALTERNATE TO SQL GROUPBY (such as to avoid repeating on aggregate fields)

Tags: sql, group-by

Is there any way to have a query return say 8 fields but only group by one field and perform only one aggregate function on another field? 
I get an error that suggests that i need to group by by all fields that do not have aggregate functions.

I need to find the number of completed surveys for each month but need to include other information such as session starttime, session status, session id, etc.

When I try to execute this:

```
SELECT Datepart("m", starttime), 
       COUNT(sessionid), 
       sessionstatus, 
       starttime, 
       endtime, 
       surveyid, 
       surveybook, 
       userdesk 
FROM   survey_sessions 
GROUP  BY Datepart("m", starttime)
```

I get the error:
 "You tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'SessionStatus' as part of an aggregate function"

I do not need any other aggregates and grouping by the remaining fields does not give me ability to get the monthly total.

Comment: What DB are you using? What would you want for the other values. The values from the first row for the month. Last row. Arbitrary row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using a GROUP BY you ALWAYS have to have all of the fields selected included within the GROUP BY no matter what.

If you include everything in the group by clause you probably aren't going to get the results you were expecting because I'm assuming that every row is pretty much unique when grouping on that many columns.

Assuming you're using SQL Server could try:

```
SELECT Datepart("m", starttime), 
   COUNT(sessionid) OVER(PARTITION BY Datepart("m", starttime)) AS Count, 
   sessionstatus, 
   starttime, 
   endtime, 
   surveyid, 
   surveybook, 
   userdesk 
FROM   survey_sessions
```

This will display the all the information you are looking for with a count of how many occured in the month displayed on each row.

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to accomplish so it's hard to be more specific.

EDIT: Adding alternate solution for access.

If you need it to work in access as well you could try your you could try the following. Replace the '' with a number, date, or string that corresponds with the data-type the first query returns. This will place rows at the bottom of your query with the total for each month.

```
SELECT Datepart("m", starttime), 
   0 AS COUNT
   sessionstatus, 
   starttime, 
   endtime, 
   surveyid, 
   surveybook, 
   userdesk 
FROM   survey_sessions 

UNION ALL 

SELECT Datepart("m", starttime),
   COUNT(sessionid) as Count,
   '',
   '',
   '',
   '',
   '',
   ''
FROM survey_sessions
GROUP BY Datepart("m", starttime)
```

Comment: This works for sequel server, but unfortunately I need a solution for access as well. I searched around and couldn't find anything that give the same result. In access I get the error: Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'COUNT(sessionid) OVER(PARTITION BY Datepart("m", starttime))'

Comment: Try the above edit at the bottom. I'm not sure if it does entirely what you are looking for, but it will add a row with the counts at the bottom and still return all of the data rows as well.

Comment: This works well. You you left a comma after '0 AS COUNT' and 'COUNT(sessionid) as Count' but otherwise its exactly what I needed. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

[Since searches for the error message](https://www.google.com/#hl=en&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&q=You+tried+to+execute+a+query+that+does+not+include+the+specified+expression&pbx=1&oq=You+tried+to+execute+a+query+that+does+not+include+the+specified+expression&aq=f&aqi=g3g-v1&aql=&gs_sm=3&gs_upl=606l606l0l717l1l1l0l0l0l0l91l91l1l1l0&gs_l=hp.3..0l3j0i15.606l606l0l717l1l1l0l0l0l0l91l91l1l1l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=2662c7bf2252b838&biw=1163&bih=828) point to MS-Access  the easiest way is to use first

```
SELECT Datepart("m", starttime), 
       COUNT(sessionid), 
       FIRST(sessionstatus), 
       FIRST(starttime), 
       FIRST(endtime), 
       FIRST(surveyid), 
       FIRST(surveybook), 
       FIRST(userdesk) 
FROM   survey_sessions 
GROUP  BY Datepart("m", starttime)
```

If you looking to simulate `COUNT OVER` you can so an inline view (using two because I don't think expressions work in Access SQL

```
 SELECT 
         main.Month,
         q.Kount,
         main.sessionstatus, 
         main.starttime, 
         main.endtime, 
         main.surveyid, 
         main.surveybook, 
         main.userdesk,
         main.sessionstatus
   FROM
    (SELECT Datepart("m", s.starttime) month, 

       s.sessionstatus, 
       s.starttime, 
       s.endtime, 
       s.surveyid, 
       s.surveybook, 
       s.userdesk 
      FROM   survey_sessions) main 
     INNER JOIN (SELECT Datepart("m", starttime) [MONTH],
                         COUNT(sessionid) kount
                   FROM survey_sessions 
                   GROUP BY Datepart("m", starttime)) q
       ON main.month = q.month
```

Comment: This is extremely useful and answers the specific question I posted, however it turns out that the partition solution is what I needed in general since it displays all rows. However, I cannot vote up on your answer because I do not have enough reputation points. :-(

Comment: @CuriousKodj I've give you an additional query that that simulates `COUNT OVER` I feel like DCOUNT might also work but its been awhile

Comment: This works well. I just had to add a group by clause to the inner join and some other little details. I'm not sure which solution is less expensive (compared to the union all solution above) but I will figure that out. i really appreciate the speedy replies!! You guys are awesome!!!

Answer (score 0):

You are grouping on one column but you are having multiple columns in SELECT clause...

Comment: PS: I dont have authentication to comment on the posted questions due to my rep.

Answer (score 0):

There's no harm in including all of the non-aggregated columns in the `GROUP BY` clause. Typically it's just a simple copy and paste from the select columns. Syntax-wise, it is a little duplicative, but it yields the same results. Your new query:

```
SELECT 
     Datepart("m", starttime) 
    ,COUNT(sessionid)
    ,sessionstatus
    ,starttime
    ,endtime
    ,surveyid
    ,surveybook 
    ,userdesk 
FROM survey_sessions 
GROUP BY 
     Datepart("m", starttime)
    ,sessionstatus
    ,starttime
    ,endtime
    ,surveyid
    ,surveybook 
    ,userdesk
```

Comment: I guessed you missed the part from the question "grouping by the remaining fields does not give me ability to get the monthly total."